# pgfplots jump mid mark with two ends

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to make this plot in tikz-pgfplots. But I'm not sure how to get the jump mid marks with two ends. Any thoughts? Also are the coordinates correctly assigned in the proper format here as I'm getting an error?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\makebox[\textwidth]
  {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=15cm,
change y base,
y unit=microns,
ytick scale label code/.code={},
ytick={1,...,12},
scaled y ticks=base 10:-6,
xtick={1,...,12},
ylabel=Particle type,
xlabel=Particle diameter $\mu$ m,
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}{}},
symbolic y coords= {{Human Hair}    ,
{Skin Flakes}   ,
{Dus in air}    ,
{Common Pollens}    ,
{Mite Allergens}    ,
{Common Spores} ,
{Bacteria}  ,
{Cat Dander}    ,
{Tobacco Smoke} ,
{Metal  and}    ,
{Cell Debris}   ,
{Viruses}},
    grid=major,
]

\addplot+[jump mark mid,ybar,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] 
coordinates
{
(   {Human Hair} ,  25  )+-(    100 ,   150 )
(   {Skin Flakes} , 30  )+-(    20  ,   40  )
(   {Dust in air} , 10  )+-(    10  ,   100 )
(   {Common Pollens} ,  20  )+-(    15  ,   25  )
(   {Mite Allergens} ,  15  )+-(    10  ,   20  )
(   {Common Spores} ,   10  )+-(    10  ,   15  )
(   {Bacteria} ,    1   )+-(    0.1 ,   2   )
(   {Cat Dander} ,  1   )+-(    0.1 ,   0.5 )
(   {Tobacco Smoke} ,   0.001   )+-(    0.001   ,   0.005   )
(   {Metal and} ,   0.001   )+-(    0.001   ,   0.001   )
(   {Cell Debris} , 0.1 )+-(    0.1 ,   1000    )
(   {Viruses},  0.1 )+-(    0.01    ,   0.5 )


};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

 \smallskip
 \caption{Particle diameter ranges $\mu$m}
  \label{fig:part_diam}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would (ab)use the error mark functionality (as it seems you intended to as well), and provide the data as a table instead of using the `coordinates` keyword:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Label, Start, Range
Human Hair, 25,100
Skin Flakes, 30,20
Dust in air, 10,10
Common Pollens,  20,15
Mite Allergens,  15,10
Common Spores,   10,10
Bacteria,    1,1
Cat Dander,  1,1
Tobacco Smoke,   0.001,0.001
Metal and,   0.001,0.001
Cell Debris, 0.1,0.1
Viruses,  0.1,0.1
}\datatable

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log,
ylabel=Particle type,
xlabel=Particle diameter $\mu$m,
ytick=data,
yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label},
]

\addplot [
    very thick,
    only marks,
    mark=|,
    error bars/.cd,
        x dir=plus,
        x explicit,
        error bar style={very thick},
        error mark=|,
        error mark options={draw, very thick}
    ] 
table [col sep=comma, y expr=\coordindex, x index=1, x error index=2]
{\datatable};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very sleek indeed! And of course very much appreciated!

Comment: I learn something useful every day!  Going to go a play around with the format of the bars (if I can find a way to get the diamonds on the ends).

Comment: @HCAI: You can! Just change `mark=|` to `mark=diamond*` and `error mark=|` to `error mark=diamond*`